# How to indicate the specific datapoint on the XY am4chart upon clicking on it?

Tags: angular, line, amcharts, amcharts4, timeserieschart

It may seem really trivial but I haven't been able to find the solution for my problem anywhere. So I have a classic XY am4chart with couple hundreds data points in the line series. I want the chart to draw a vertical line (or indicate in any other way) upon clicking on the given point in chart. So if I click once then the indication appears in that point and if I click somewhere else on the chart - the indication moves to the new place. Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can trigger the cursor when a point is clicked. Here is an example:

```js
// Themes begin
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
// Themes end

// Create chart instance
var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);

// Add data
chart.data = [{
  "date": new Date(2018, 3, 20),
  "value": 90
}, {
  "date": new Date(2018, 3, 21),
  "value": 102
}, {
  "date": new Date(2018, 3, 22),
  "value": 65
}, {
  "date": new Date(2018, 3, 23),
  "value": 62
}, {
  "date": new Date(2018, 3, 24),
  "value": 55
}, {
  "date": new Date(2018, 3, 25),
  "value": 81
}];

// Create axes
var dateAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());

// Create value axis
var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());

// Create cursor
chart.cursor = new am4charts.XYCursor();
chart.cursor.yAxis = valueAxis;
chart.cursor.lineX.disabled = true;
chart.cursor.interactionsEnabled = false;
chart.cursor.events.on("track", event => {
  chart.cursor.hide();
  chart.cursor.interactionsEnabled = false;
});

// Create series
var lineSeries = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
lineSeries.dataFields.valueY = "value";
lineSeries.dataFields.dateX = "date";
lineSeries.name = "Sales";
lineSeries.strokeWidth = 3;

// Add simple bullet
var bullet = lineSeries.bullets.push(new am4charts.Bullet());
var image = bullet.createChild(am4core.Image);
image.href = "https://www.amcharts.com/lib/images/star.svg";
image.width = 30;
image.height = 30;
image.horizontalCenter = "middle";
image.verticalCenter = "middle";
// attach click event
bullet.events.on("hit", event => {
  chart.cursor.interactionsEnabled = true;
  var point = event.target.dataItem.point;
  chart.cursor.triggerMove(point);
});
```

[image]